# weird behavior with printf ()

Tags: c, printf

So I'm unable to get printf to output anything while being in nested for loops

for example:

```
printf("hello ");
for(int i =0; i< 4; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   printf("world");
```

This would only out the word hello without being able to output the word "world". I tried fflush(stdout), but it seem that the command was unable to solve the problem. I'm using a Mac. Can some one give a suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Shall we *guess* what `size1` and `size2` are ? Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you initialized the variables `size1` and `size2`?

Comment: yes i did in my code, this is just an example code I use to demonstrate the problem. Oh well i shall put some number in there now just to prevent from being subtract point for this post

Comment: just to interpret the above:  "world" is printed inside a doubly nested for loop.  For loops execute conditionally, possibly never, so check your loop conditions.

Comment: if i delete a loop and  use only 1 loop then "world "  have no problem to be printed out. However, When I use nested for loops, nothing get to print out

Comment: Did you try running it now, it prints exactly what it's supposed to do,print `hello worldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworldworld`

Comment: Seems to work fine? http://codepad.org/gOsraX1k

Comment: I did, I never have this problem before. I don't know if it has anything to do with codelite ide or the mac

Comment: https://ideone.com/EUHmeB, i tried to use ideone and it still only output hello

Comment: Aside from the rage-inducing indentation, there's nothing wrong with the code you've posted.  There is a problem with your actual context somewhere.   Note that if you're running C-code like this on the command line, it can sometimes get blitzed by the console prompt that gets written after the program completes... so put a `printf("\n");` after your loops to make sure that's not happening.

Comment: Look carefully at your conditional in the outer loop on that ideone link

Comment: oh sorry, it was my fault. I make a mistake when typing the condition for the outer loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code provided in the link [link](https://ideone.com/EUHmeB) is that

```
for( i = 0; i > m; i++)
```

The condition you have used is `i > m` when it should have been `i < m`.

Comment: yes, thank you I realize that too after carefully looking at the code, sorry for posting the question too hasty

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you are doing experiments with outputting using printf and loops. And first you have program:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("hello ");
    return 0;
}
```

and this program successfully compiled and works.

Than you add loops, like:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("hello ");
    for(int i =0; i< 4; i++)
       for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            printf("world ");
    return 0;
}
```

And press magic button in your IDE - this button (or hot keys combination) should recompile your project and start your program.... but it didn't... and just run the previously compiled code (without loops).

So, carefully check the messages from the compiler, and then try the following (after each step try to compile and run your program again):

1) put counters declaration at the beginning of your program:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("hello ");
    for(i = 0; i< 4; i++)
       for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            printf("world ");
    return 0;
}
```

2) rename your file with source code to *.cpp

3) clean and rebuild your project (these are special options of IDE that ensure that all previsions compiled parts of program will be deleted and new one will be built)

Comment: I just want to point out that the problem was a typo, the code @user1763658 has provided in the question is not the code he was getting problems with. In the question, that problem is fixed, but in his original code, there was a typo.

Comment: O.k. I understand, so user1763658 must delete or close the issue